# R : how create a loop to calculate cumulated survival at a specific day

Tags: r, loops

I looked through the posted questions/responses but did not find what i am looking for and i think that i am not mastering R sufficiently to get it by myself.

The context: my dataset comes from an experimentation with analysis of biomarkers on animals("animal1", "animal2", ...,"animaln"), with different treatments ("a", "b" or "c"), different replicates per treatments ("a1", "a2" and "a3" for treatment "a", etc), and different days of measurements ("0", "5", "10" and "20"). In the dataframe i have a variable "status" that informs on the survival of the animal (=1) or death (=0) at the day x.

Here is an example of the type of structure:

```
> str(data.set)
'data.frame':   108 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ animal   : Factor w/ 27 levels "animal1","animal10",..: 1 12 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 2 ...
 $ treatment: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ replicate: Factor w/ 9 levels "a1","a2","a3",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ day      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ status   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ marker   : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I want a loop that allows me to calculate automatically the number of survival per treatment (and/or per replicate) at a specific day.

example: at day=20, the treatment "a" has still 10 animals alive, while the treatment "b" has 8 and the "c" has 5.

I hope that my explanation was clear. I tried to find a loop by myself but really I don't get to anything... I think that such loop would be very helpful for many biologists being quite beginners with the R commands...

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: It would be helpful to post the output of `dput(head(data.set))`

Comment: It seems that you need things like `aggregate(status ~ treatment + replicate + day, data.set, sum)` etc. I guess you'll find many helpful relevant "summarize by factors" QAs here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments,

Comment: i don't know the "aggregate" function, i will try to find out how does it work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the command, which in fact is very easy but i did not know the aggregate function before, so in my case there is no need for creating a loop... :

aggregate(status~group+day, data=data.set, sum)

this works ! thank you alexis_laz

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output asked :

```
dput(head(data.set))
structure(list(animal = structure(c(1L, 12L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L
), .Label = c("animal1", "animal10", "animal11", "animal12", 
"animal13", "animal14", "animal15", "animal16", "animal17", "animal18", 
"animal19", "animal2", "animal20", "animal21", "animal22", "animal23", 
"animal24", "animal25", "animal26", "animal27", "animal3", "animal4", 
"animal5", "animal6", "animal7", "animal8", "animal9"), class = "factor"), 
    treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c"), class = "factor"), replicate = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", 
    "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"), class = "factor"), day = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), status = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), marker = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("animal", "treatment", "replicate", 
"day", "status", "marker"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```